# Ошибка при запуске Excel: «Не удалось получить фабрику класса COM»

Tags: c#, winforms, excel

Я создал две кнопки которые должны открывать `Word` и `Excel`. `Word` открывает, а вот `Excel` не открывает. Я сначала хотел в одной кнопке открывать `Word` и `Excel`, потом создал отдельную кнопку. Вот исходный код:

```
private void OpenExcelAndWord_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Word.Application wordapp = new Word.Application();
    wordapp.Visible = true;  
}

private void buttonExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Excel.Application excelapp = new Excel.Application();
    excelapp.Visible = true;
}
```

Вот ошибка:

[image: ошибка при открытии Excel]

Comment: Вручную (не из приложения) Excel открывается?

Comment: Да, открывается.

Comment: А вы не хотите использовать Open XML или библиотеки, основанные на нём? Так как с Office COM Interop намучаетесь, к тому же там проблемы с быстродействием и утечками памяти. У меня лично были также проблемы с версиями.

Comment: Можете показать на примере?

Comment: Как подключить ClosedXML? Я скачал из этого сайта https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML

Comment: Все нашёл как подключить))))) CloseXML.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего, одна версия офиса была установлена поверх другой. У меня была подобного рода проблема.

Решил с помощью [этой](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/dd052f27-20d6-4b6b-9d8b-fe4fd9c6b9fc/broke-excel-interop-com-assembly-after-installingremoving-2013-beta-release?forum=exceldev) ссылки.

---

1. Откройте **Редактор реестра** (это можно сделать из командной строки, набрав `regedit`).
2. Затем в окне редактора под значком компьютера раскройте пункт `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`, потом `TypeLib`.
3. Далее найдите ключ `{00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}`. Если там более одной папки (из-за двух установленных версий), то одну из них следует удалить. Насколько я помню, у меня были папки 1.7 и 1.8, и когда я удалил одну из них, проблема разрешилась.

Возможно, и вашу проблему можно решить, удалив MS Office, а затем заново установив его.